# Структура данных HashMap

Tags: java

Подскажите, полез к HashMap под капот после прочтения пару статей. И не могу понять, HashMap был изменён или я смотрю не туда.

Первый же метод put() не содержит таких методов, как indexFor(), putForNullKey(), если он действительно был изменён, есть ли место, где я могу просмотреть его "краткую форму" или комментарии к данным, а то очень не хочется вникать/расплетать глубокие циклы методов.

Что касается статей:
[Раз](http://www.codenuclear.com/how-hashmap-works-java/), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/128017/).

Answer (score 1):

В статье на Хабре есть [ссылка на код HashMap в JDK7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l386), который соответствует описанию.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

Что касается JDK8 и выше, то да, код `HashMap` изменился как в плане функциональности (например, поддержка Stream API), так и в плане производительности (например, [улучшение алгоритма разрешения коллизий](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180)).